# how to prevent tr and td height from expanding to fit their content?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p style="font-size: 40px">rawradical<p></td>
    <td>steaf</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>frage</td>
    <td>hrae</td>
    <td>plorais</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>stufa</td>
    <td>steis</td>
    <td>arcane</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>postrene</td>
    <td>radini</td>
    <td>postina</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like the rawradical p to not interfere with the size of the rest, and have it overflow instead of changing the height of the entire row. Do anyone know how to make this happen?
table-layout: fixed; didn't work for me.

I also tried fixing it by changing the max-height of both the tr and the td, even the table, but nothing did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

One method might be to create a `div` placed over the table. The overflowing text is positioned inside the `div`, while the table cell below is left empty. I added a border to show that the table layout isn't changed by the larger text.

I would also recommend to size your font with `rem` instead of `px`, as this will resize proportionately when using different devices.

```css
#topdiv {
  font-size: 3rem;
  top: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  color: rgba(51, 170, 51, 0.7);
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="topdiv">Rawradical</div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border style="1px solid black;">
  <tr>
  <td class="big"></td>
    <td>steaf</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>frage</td>
    <td>hrae</td>
    <td>plorais</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>stufa</td>
    <td>steis</td>
    <td>arcane</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>postrene</td>
    <td>radini</td>
    <td>postina</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Unfortunately this still interferes with the table as it changes the position of the td. I plan for my table to have a background soon enough, which makes a little mess with this solution. I really need the td to stay in its place as well as the structure of the table, but have the content overflow nonetheless

Comment: @WXLPMNB it's difficult to effectively adjust text inside a table, a better method might be to use a `div` based grid instead of a table. However you could also layer the large text above the table. I edited my answer to show how this might work.